# Does hadoop list command show jobs having state other than 1?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know that `hadoop job -list` commnad lists *currently running jobs*, i.e. jobs whose state is **1 (Running)**. But does it list jobs which are failed? I mean can I get an output something like this:

```
1 jobs currently running
JobId   State   StartTime       UserName
job_200808111901_0001   3       1218506470390   abc
job_200808111901_0002   2       1218506470390   xyz
```

Note that the states of the above jobs are **3 (Failed)** and **2 (Succeeded)**.

I am very new to Hadoop, so please pardon me if this too simple question. I tried to google, but all the examples give listed jobs with state 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `all` and you will get what you desire.

Execute something like: `hadoop job -list all`.

An example output would look something like the following:

```
$ hadoop job -list all
0 jobs submitted
States are:
    Running : 1 Succeded : 2    Failed : 3  Prep : 4
JobId   State   StartTime   UserName    Priority    SchedulingInfo
```

For more details about the hadoop commands and especialy `hadoop job`, read [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/commands_manual.html#job).